# How to do parameterized mapping using MapStruct in Java?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have following entity class

```
public class Company {

    private Map<Locale, String> name;

    /* Other fields, getters, setters */
}
```

And the following DTO class

```
public class CompanyHeader {

    private String name;

    /* Other fields, getters, setters */
}
```

So, my entity contains names for different languages, and I want to map it for a given `Locale`

Here's my mapper class

```
@Mapper
public interface CompanyMapper {

    CompanyHeader entityToHeader(Company company, Locale locale);

    @Named("getByLocale")
    default String getValueByLocale(Map<Locale, String> map, Locale locale) {
        return map.get(locale);
    }
}
```

And now my question is, how should I annotate my mapping method so that it understands `company` as my source object, `getValueByLocale` method as a mapping method for `name` field, and `locale` as a parameter for `getValueByLocale` method?

Here's how I use my mapping method from outside

```
public Page<CompanyHeader> getCompanies(CompanyFilter companyFilter, Locale locale) {
    Page<Company> companies = getCompanies(companyFilter);
    Page<CompanyHeader> headers = companies.map(company -> companyMapper.entityToHeader(company, locale));

    return headers;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to solve seems like a good usage for `@Context`.

If you define your mapper like

```
@Mapper
public interface CompanyMapper {

    CompanyHeader entityToHeader(Company company, @Coontext Locale locale);

    default String getValueByLocale(Map<Locale, String> map, @Context Locale locale) {
        return map.get(locale);
    }
}
```

By using `@Context` you are telling MapStrut that this object should not be seen as a mapping object and that it can be passed to other objects. With this method you are going to be able to map all `Map<Locale, String>` properties into a `String`.

You can read more about `@Context` in the [Passing context or state objects to custom methods](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#passing-context)